# Fetch a single column by a multi select

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would save the id of each user in a session for get later name ... in my login system. I would do that on each login. 
But the problem: If i Select more columns with the sql i cant fetch a single column.
How i can fetch one column even tough i selected more columns in the sql.

I tried something like that:

```
    $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['password']
```

But it isn´t working on my code:

```
    $sth = $X['dbh']->prepare("SELECT `password` `id` FROM `users` WHERE `uid` = :uid; ");
          if (! $sth->execute(array(
            ':uid' => $X['param']['uid'],
          ))) {
          //check for right name, passwort ... 
          }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How i can fetch one column even tough i selected more columns in the sql.

Nohow.

Either select only one column, or fetch all that you have selected. Otherwise it would make no sense to select.

And after fetching an array, you can access its members all right.

```
$user = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$pass = $user['password'];
```

then later in the code you can use `$user['id']` as well.

Comment: I need the id later in my code, but i would do like in your anwser. Thank you !

Comment: Will fetch retrieve the full dataset (and pick the top row), or limit the dataset to 1 row?